# sed how to delete text and symbols between

Tags: bash, sed

I have sql file with this strings :

```
(17, 14, '2015-01-20 10:38:40', 211, 'Just text\n\nFrom: Support  &lt;support@domain.com&gt;\n Send: 20 Jan 2015 year. 10:33\n To: Admin\n Theme: [TST #0000014] Just text \n\nJust text: Text\n Test text test text\n\nJust text:\n Text\n\n-- \n Test\n Text.\n Many text words 0.84.2', 0, 2);
```

I want remove all text between symbols `\n\` and `', 0, 2);`
I want get this result:

```
(17, 14, '2015-01-20 10:38:40', 211, 'Just text', 0, 2);
```

How I can do it via sed?

I try use this example - `cat file | sed 's/<b>.*</b>//g'`. I changed `<b>` to `\n\` and `</b>` to `', 0, 2);` But it dont work, I get error in console

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I try use this example - cat file | sed 's/<b>.*</b>//g'  I changed <b> to \n\ and </b> to ', 0, 2); But it dont work, I get error in console

Comment: @Darkwind add the above to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this command

```
sed 's/\\n\\.*\('\'', 0, 2);\)/\1/g' FileName
```

**Output :**

```
(17, 14, '2015-01-20 10:38:40', 211, 'Just text', 0, 2);
```

You have to escape the single quotes like `'\''`  as well as back slash `\\`

Answer (score 0):

If you can find it, you can replace it with nothing.

So, depending on what you mean by `\n` and what you need to escape, you want something like `sed 's/\\n\\.*'//g'`.

Obviously, take care that this is *really* what you want to replace on every line.  It might be worth searching for the target `\\n\\.*'` first, to make sure it doesn't accidentally grab too much on an unexpected line.